# Android Studio / Cambio de fragments de un Navigation Drawer programáticamente

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy teniendo un error de superposición de fragments cuando intento cambiarlos programáticamente.

**Adjunto imágen donde se puede ver que hay un fragment por encima de otro (aclaro que el fragment que está por encima que es un chat, puede ser usado pero el de abajo solo está como fondo y no es funcional)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Adjunto el código de la actividad que contiene el navigation drawer, el cual es el responsable de detectar la selección de los nav_items**

```
NavigationView nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
            int menu_id = menuItem.getItemId();

            Fragment fragment = null;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            switch(menu_id) {
                case R.id.nav_inicio:
                    fragment = new fragment_inicio();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "inicio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_perfil:
                    fragment = new fragment_perfil();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "PERFIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_chat:
                    fragment = new fragment_chat();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "CHAT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment).commit();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Adjunto el código XML de content_main (layout que crea Android Studio por defecto al crear una app de tipo Navigation Drawer)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Edit: Código java en el cual obtengo error dentro del MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    nombree = findViewById(R.id.et_ciudad);

    abc = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.nav_inicio, R.id.nav_perfil, 
R.id.nav_chat, R.id.nav_buscar, R.id.nav_mis_clases, R.id.nav_ayuda, 
R.id.nav_configuracion)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer).build();
    //LÍNEA EN LA CUAL OBTENGO ERROR
    nc = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nv, nc);

    nv.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_inicio);

    nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
.
.
.}
```

**Gracias por leer**

Comment: agrega a los xml de los fragments esta propiedad: android:background="?android:colorBackground"

Comment: que Android Studio no te crea  NavController y AppBarConfiguration para la navegación de fragments? Estas mezclando 2 formas de navegación (Navigation y Fragment Transaction)

Comment: me ha pasado el mismo error que a ti, y veo que lo has solucionado poniendo el fragment nav_host_fragment como un FrameLayour, pero eso hace que se pierdan otras funcionalidades del Navigation Drawer creado por Android Studio, ¿ como lo has resuelto?

Comment: Lo solucione tal y como me dijo Jorgesys. Además, tu comentario no debería ser una respuesta. Te recomiendo leer las instrucciones de stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeramente debes cambiar el valor de retorno del listener a `true`, ya que este valor booleano determina si el evento se consume o no:

```
nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
            ...
            ...
            ...

            //return false;
            return true;

        }
    });
```

Ahora con respecto a porque se ve un `Fragment` debajo aùn y cuando realizaste la transacción del `Fragment`.

Te sugiero que en lugar de definir un `Fragment` uses un `FrameLayout` que sería donde realizarías el reemplazo de los Fragments:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
```

Comment: Perfecto Jorge, me ayudaste una vez mas a resolver un problema. Me funcionó perfecto el código. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Excelente @TomasM, saludos